# Unable to add a class to an element with jQuery, can someone please assist?

Tags: jquery, addclass

For some reason I can't seem to add a class to my 'li' tag using jQuery, I've done this before but I've been stuck on this for over an hour and can't see what I'm doing wrong!?

Can anyone see a mistake in this? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks! :)

```
<nav>
    <ul id="tabs">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#tabs li:first').addClass('active');
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in your console? (Psst, you have one too many `});`).

Answer (score 2):

You have redundant closing brackets:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tabs li:first').addClass('active');
    }); // <-- Remove this
}); // <-- or this
```

Comment: Also start to look for JS errors on the browser console. It's really helpful.

Comment: Or, rather remove the first one, since this one is tabbed correctly :-)

Comment: Unbeleivable, kicking myself right now :). thanks so much. Will upvote in 12 mins when it lets me!